# How to convert GPS Lat Lng coordinates to Arcgis X,Y values?

Tags: android, gps, arcgis

I am developing one application using arcgis ,I want to show current location on map with marker.I am getting lat lng values from gps.Here I have problem while displaying marker on map,i.e the marker shows in see not in map, it is not showing current location on map.Please any one solve my Problem

my Mainclass with arcgis map

```
GPSTracker gpsTracker=new GPSTracker(LaunchingMapActivity.this);
double locx = gpsTracker.getLatitude();
double locy = gpsTracker.getLongitude();
Log.e("locx",""+locx);
Log.e("locy",""+locy);
Point mapPoint=new Point(locx,locy);

Point wgspoint=mMapView.toMapPoint(mapPoint);

Point currentPoint=mMapView.toMapPoint(wgspoint);

                              Point mapPoint = (Point) GeometryEngine.project(currentPoint,  

                                      SpatialReference.create(4322),

                                      mMapView.getSpatialReference());

                                      Unit mapUnit = mMapView.getSpatialReference().getUnit();
                                      double SEARCH_RADIUS = 0;
                                    double zoomWidth = Unit.convertUnits(

                                      SEARCH_RADIUS, Unit.create(LinearUnit.Code.MILE_US),                                                    
                                    mapUnit);
                                      Envelope zoomExtent = new Envelope(mapPoint, zoomWidth,                 
                                    zoomWidth);

                             mMapView.setExtent(zoomExtent);

                                      gLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
                                      PictureMarkerSymbol symbol = new     





        PictureMarkerSymbol(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.markerpointblue));
                                      Graphic graphic = new Graphic(mapPoint, symbol);
                                      //Graphic point=new Graphic(new Point(x, y),new    
                                   //   SimpleMarkerSymbol(Color.CYAN,20,STYLE.CIRCLE);

                                    roadGeometiesList.add(graphic.getGeometry());
                                    Geometry[] geoArr = roadGeometiesList
                                            .toArray(new Geometry[roadGeometiesList.size()]);
                                    share.setGeoArr(geoArr);

                                     gLayer.addGraphic(graphic);
                                      mMapView .addLayer(gLayer);
```

}

```
My GpsTracker

  package au.com.ipptechnologies.gps;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;



public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

   private final Context mContext;

   // flag for GPS status
   boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

   // flag for network status
   boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

   // flag for GPS status
   boolean canGetLocation = false;

   Location location; // location
   double latitude; // latitude
   double longitude; // longitude
   double speed;

   // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
   private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

   // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
   private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

   // Declaring a Location Manager
   protected LocationManager locationManager;

   public GPSTracker(Context context) {
       this.mContext = context;
       getLocation();
   }

   public Location getLocation() {
       try {
           locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                   .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);



           Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
           criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW); // Chose your desired power consumption level.
           criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE); // Choose your accuracy requirement.
           criteria.setSpeedRequired(true); 
           criteria.setSpeedAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);// Chose if speed for first location fix is required.
           criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false); // Choose if you use altitude.
           criteria.setBearingRequired(false); // Choose if you use bearing.
           criteria.setCostAllowed(false); // Choose if this provider can waste money :-)


           // getting GPS status
           isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                   .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);



           // getting network status
           isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                   .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);


           if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
               // no network provider is enabled
           } else {
               this.canGetLocation = true;
               if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                   locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                           LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                           MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                           MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                   Log.d("Network", "Network");
                   if (locationManager != null) {
                       location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                      // locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
                       if (location != null) {
                           latitude = location.getLatitude();
                           longitude = location.getLongitude();
                       }
                   }
               }
               // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
               if (isGPSEnabled) {
                   if (location == null) {
                       locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                               LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                               MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                               MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                       Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                       if (locationManager != null) {
                           location = locationManager
                                   .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                           if (location != null) {
                               latitude = location.getLatitude();
                               longitude = location.getLongitude();
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
           }

       } catch (Exception e) {
       }
       return location;
   }

   /**
    * Stop using GPS listener Calling this function will stop using GPS in your
    * app.
    * */
   public void stopUsingGPS() {
       if (locationManager != null) {
           locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
       }
   }

   /**
    * Function to get latitude
    * */
   public double getLatitude() {
       if (location != null) {
           latitude = location.getLatitude();

       }
       // return latitude
       return latitude;
   }

   /**
    * Function to get longitude
    * */
   public double getLongitude() {
       if (location != null) {
           longitude = location.getLongitude();
       }

       // return longitude
       return longitude;
   }
   public double getCurrentSpeed(){
     if (location != null) {
     if(location.hasSpeed()){

     Log.e("HasSpeed", ""+location.hasSpeed());
           speed = location.getSpeed();
     }
       }
     return speed;
   }

   /**
    * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
    * 
    * @return boolean
    * */
   public boolean canGetLocation() {
       return this.canGetLocation;
   }

   /**
    * Function to show settings alert dialog On pressing Settings button will
    * lauch Settings Options
    * */
   public void showSettingsAlert() {
       AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

       // Setting DialogHelp Title
       alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

       // Setting DialogHelp Message
       alertDialog
               .setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

       // On pressing Settings button
       alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",
               new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                       Intent intent = new Intent(
                               Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                       mContext.startActivity(intent);
                   }
               });

       // on pressing cancel button
       alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
               new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                       dialog.cancel();
                   }
               });

       // Showing Alert Message
       alertDialog.show();
   }

   @Override
   public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
       float bestAccuracy = -1f;
       if (location.getAccuracy() != 0.0f
           && (location.getAccuracy() < bestAccuracy) || bestAccuracy == -1f) {
               locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
       }
       bestAccuracy = location.getAccuracy();
   }

   @Override
   public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
   }

   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
       return null;
   }

   public float getAccurecy()
   {
       return location.getAccuracy();
   }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

What is the spatial reference of your base map?
You might need to re-project your point geometries before plotting them on the map so they have the same spatial reference as the basemap.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/geometryservice-amd.html#project